# Do we want to allow Community ads for real apps?

Tags: discussion, community-ads

I may be getting waaaaay ahead of ourselves here, but after beta (whenever that may be), there *may* be the option for community adverts -- what is people's feeling about some of these being for real apps?

On some of the more development focussed Stack Exchanges, the ads have been used for open source projects (etc), but I am sure there are many apps that are similarly worthy (perhaps an app that makes charitable donation easier?)

Comment: I like the idea, but I am not sure about the execution. On photo.se, they have a picture of the week that is chosen by popular vote. Perhaps the same concept can work here. A weekly vote is held for a featured app?

Comment: That could also work -- I was thinking more like [those on StackOverflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93312/130044)

Comment: I like your idea @RowlandShaw. It will be very focused.